# customizing session cookie Rails Api

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, session-cookies, samesite

With the recent changes from chrome now being live, I have run into the issue where my session cookies are not being saved by the browser because they lack Secure/SameSite. I originally followed a guide from Medium, [article here](https://medium.com/how-i-get-it/react-with-rails-user-authentication-8977e98762f2). However, after further searching on StackOverflow and online you are *supposed* to be able to customize the cookie. However, I have noticed that both the customer key name I am setting and any other variables are not actually applying to the cookie. Since this cookie locks actions away behind an admin and that cookie is no longer working I cant do any admin tasks while on chrome.

session_store.rb file

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_dbfz_session', expire_after: 14.days
```

Comment: The `SameSite=Lax` by default changes will only affect cross-site requests. Is your set-up running across multiple sites? e.g. your cookie domain is `auth-server.example` and your app is on `client-app.example`. If everything is running from the same site, this may be a different issue.

Comment: So it's a rails API backend and react front end on different domains.